# Verify if an attribute of a java object is null

Tags: java, class, object

I have this java class, but in the printLista method I'm verifying if the attribute is null but I don't know why never gets into the cycle even though is not null, actually it works backwards, when I don't define the attribute and it is null gets into the cycle

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lista myList = new Lista(3);
        
        myList.setCola(new Lista(8));

        myList.printLista();
    }
}


public class Lista{
    public int head;
    public Lista cola;

    public Lista(int head){
        this.head = head;
        this.cola = null;
    }

    public int getHead(){
        return this.head;
    }

    public Lista getCola(){
        return this.cola;
    }

    public void setCola(Lista cola){
        this.cola = cola;
    }

    public void printLista(){

        Lista nodo = this.getCola();

        while(nodo.cola != null){
            System.out.println(nodo.getHead());
            nodo = nodo.getCola();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lista myList = new Lista(3);
> This line create a new Lista object with head 3 and cola null.

> myList.setCola(new Lista(8));
> This line first creates a new Lista object with head 8 and cola null. It then sets this new object as the cola for myList.

> Lista nodo = this.getCola();
> This line in printLista method will get the cola of myLista, which is the object created in step 2. Hence nodo will have head 8 and cola null.

Since nodo.cola is null, the while loop is not executed.

Comment: Yeah, I  see the problem, thanks!